# Converting the epoch to normal datetime with condition R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame, where in three columns it has epoch time stored in it.

As shown below in `Time` column the whole column contains epoch but in `Result` and `Result_2` column only some let say cells containing epoch time.

**ABC_1**

```
Sr.No.  Stage           Time            Result          Result_2
    1       updated_date    1516868822411   1516868822361   1516868822350
    2       id              1516868822411   ABC             -
    3       engine_date     1516868822411   1516868822000   -
    4       blocked         1516868822411   80000           0
    5       updated_date    1516868822398   1516868822350   1516866877815
    6       list            1516868822398   BCD             -
    7       sub_stat_1      1516868779095   AC-12           AC-14
    8       status_1        1516868642468   AC-25           AC-38
```

Now i need this data frame expand with three more columns (i.e Time_2, Final_1 & Final_2).

Where Time_2 gives the output of Time (DF-ABC_1) from epoch to normal, and Final_1 & Final_2 give me the output same as Result and Result_2 but wherever epoch time comes in Result and Result_2 convert it into normal time in output data frame.

**Output DF:**

```
Sr. No.    Stage   Time            Result          Result_2      Time_2                     Final_1                     Final_2
1      updated_date 1516868822411  1516868822361   1516868822350 25/01/2018 08:27:02        25/01/2018 08:27:02         25/01/2018 08:27:02
2      id           1516868822411  ABC             -             25/01/2018 08:27:02        ABC                         -
3      engine_date  1516868822411  1516868822000   -             25/01/2018 08:27:02        25/01/2018 08:27:02         -
4      blocked      1516868822411  80000           0             25/01/2018 08:27:02        80000                       0
5      updated_date 1516868822398  1516868822350   1516866877815 25/01/2018 08:27:02        25/01/2018 08:27:02         25/01/2018 07:54:38
6      list         1516868822398  BCD             -             25/01/2018 08:27:02        BCD                         -
7      sub_stat_1   1516868779095  AC-12           AC-14         25/01/2018 08:26:19        Y (Output of AC-12)         YY (Output of AC-14)
8      status_1     1516868642468  AC-25           AC-38         25/01/2018 08:24:02        A (Output of AC-25)         CC (Output of AC-38)
```

To get that desired output i have a code but it's not working properly:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
    ABC_1 <- read.csv (file = "ABC_1.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    ABC_1 %>%
      as_tibble %>%
      mutate(Time_2 = as.POSIXct(timestamp / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")) %>%

      left_join(
        ABC_1 %>%
          rename_(Result = Final_1, Result_2 = Final_2) %>%
          gather(key, value, -Sr.No., -Stage, -Time) %>%
          mutate(
            value = case_when(nchar(value) == 13 ~ suppressWarnings(strftime(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(value) / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")),
              TRUE ~ value
            )
          ) %>%
          spread(key, value),
        by = c("Sr.No.", "Stage", "Time")
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this base `R` solution:

```r
#this is to force R to display long number (i.e. epoch time values) in non scientific notation
options("scipen"=100)

df$Time_2 <- as.POSIXct(df$Time/ 1e3, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")

df$Final_1 <- sapply(df$Result, function(x) 
  ifelse(grepl('\\d{13}',x),
         as.character(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x)/ 1e3, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")),
         x))

df$Final_2 <- sapply(df$Result_2, function(x) 
  ifelse(grepl('\\d{13}',x),
         as.character(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x)/ 1e3, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")),
         x))
df
```

Output is:

```
  Sr.No.        Stage          Time        Result      Result_2              Time_2             Final_1
1      1 updated_date 1516868822411 1516868822361 1516868822350 2018-01-25 08:27:02 2018-01-25 08:27:02
2      2           id 1516868822411           ABC             - 2018-01-25 08:27:02                 ABC
3      3  engine_date 1516868822411 1516868822000             - 2018-01-25 08:27:02 2018-01-25 08:27:02
4      4      blocked 1516868822411         80000             0 2018-01-25 08:27:02               80000
5      5 updated_date 1516868822398 1516868822350 1516866877815 2018-01-25 08:27:02 2018-01-25 08:27:02
6      6         list 1516868822398           BCD             - 2018-01-25 08:27:02                 BCD
7      7   sub_stat_1 1516868779095         AC-12         AC-14 2018-01-25 08:26:19               AC-12
8      8     status_1 1516868642468         AC-25         AC-38 2018-01-25 08:24:02               AC-25
              Final_2
1 2018-01-25 08:27:02
2                   -
3                   -
4                   0
5 2018-01-25 07:54:37
6                   -
7               AC-14
8               AC-38
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(Sr.No. = 1:8, Stage = c("updated_date", "id", 
"engine_date", "blocked", "updated_date", "list", "sub_stat_1", 
"status_1"), Time = c(1516868822411, 1516868822411, 1516868822411, 
1516868822411, 1516868822398, 1516868822398, 1516868779095, 1516868642468
), Result = c("1516868822361", "ABC", "1516868822000", "80000", 
"1516868822350", "BCD", "AC-12", "AC-25"), Result_2 = c("1516868822350", 
"-", "-", "0", "1516866877815", "-", "AC-14", "AC-38")), .Names = c("Sr.No.", 
"Stage", "Time", "Result", "Result_2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Glad that it helped :)